# jQuery-ui tabs stay closed first item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have implemented the jquery-ui-tabs to my website, however I would like, when the site is loaded, all tabs stay closed, until user click the one of them.
Now, the first tab is active by itself, I don't want this functionality

I am using this tabs starter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
});
```

I suppose, I need to add something there, but I really don't know what.

Thanks for help

Comment: You can try : $("#tabs").tabs({active: false});

Comment: This works, however you need to add "collapsible:true" also